# How to make a triangle JAVA

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, nested, geometry

I need to use a nested for loop in Java to make a triangle like this

```
********
 *******
  ******
   *****
    ****
     ***
      **
       *
```

Heres my code:

```
 for (int i=8; i>0; i--)
   {
  for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
  {
      System.out.print('#');
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

I get a triangle but not the one i want

Comment: You're almost close. You can use another loop to print the spaces desired before printing the stars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it… you only forgot the spaces:

```
for (int i=8; i>0; i--) {
    // print 8-i spaces, i.e. the complement number of spaces
    for (int j=0; j<8-i; j++)
        System.out.print(' ');
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
        System.out.print('#');
    System.out.println("");
}
```